# How to add links to slideshow image... JavaScript

Tags: javascript

To anyone that can help, I created a simple JQuery slideshow using an image array. The slide show works perfectly, but now I just want to add links to each slide(picture). I just uploaded the first image in the "slides" div, which is the "joshuatreepic.psd. Then I used all three images in the script ("joshuatreepic.psd", "MSalbum.psd", "scheduleslide.png"). Here is my code...

```
<div id='slides'>
<img src="joshuatreepic.psd" id="slideshow" />
</div>

<div id='nav_links'>
<ul id='list'>
    <li class='active' id='0'><a href="#" onclick="skip_to(0)"><img src="grey-dot-
small.png" /></a></li>
    <li id='1'><a href="#" onclick="skip_to(1)"><img src="grey-dot-small.png" />
</a></li>
    <li id='2'><a href="#" onclick="skip_to(2)"><img src="grey-dot-small.png" />
</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<p class="leftarrow"><a href="#" onclick="change_image(-1)"><img
src="slideshow_arrow_left.png"></a></p>
<p class="rightarrow"><a href="#" onclick="change_image(1)"><img
src="slideshow_arrow_right.png"></a></p> 

</div>


<script type="text/javascript>
var Images = new Array("joshuatreepic.psd", "MSalbum.psd", "scheduleslide.png");
var Image_Number = 0;
var Image_Length = Images.length-1;
var Interval;
Interval = setInterval("change_image(1)", 5000);
function change_image(num) {
clearInterval(Interval);
$('#'+Image_Number).removeClass('active');
Image_Number = Image_Number + num;
if (Image_Number > Image_Length) {
    Image_Number = 0;
}
if (Image_Number < 0) {
    Image_Number = Image_Length;
}
$("#slideshow").fadeOut('slow', function () {
    $('#slideshow').attr('src', Images[Image_Number]);
    $("#"+Image_Number).addClass('active');
}).fadeIn('slow');
Interval = setInterval("change_image(1)", 5000);
}   
function skip_to(Number){
$('#'+Image_Number).removeClass('active');
Image_Number = Number;
clearInterval(Interval);
$('#slideshow').fadeOut('slow', function (){
    $('#slideshow').attr('src', Images[Image_Number]);
    $('#'+Image_Number).addClass('active'); 
}).fadeIn('slow');
Interval = setInterval("change_image(1)", 5000);
}
function play() {
 document.getElementById("play_stop").innerHTML = '<a
href="javascript:stop()">Stop</a>';
}
function stop () {
    document.getElementById("play_stop").innerHTML = '<a
href="javascript:play()">Play</a>';
clearInterval(Interval);
}
</script>
```

Comment: _“I created a simple JQuery slideshow using an image array”_ – that’s your first mistake; without JS the content will be completely unaccessible. What you should do instead, is put the images and the links you want to add into correct HTML elements in the first place, and then let your script achieve the desired effect by manipulating how these elements are display (in the simplest case by toggling between show and hide). – And on a second note – your browser displays `.psd` files, really?

Comment: create an array of targeted location or you can even add in your Images array like this `var Images = new Array({src:"myImage.png", targetUrl:"xyz.html"}...)` , in the onclick event listener you can get the element using `event.target` then just access the src property value of the image element and navigate to the corresponding location using the above array. Use `window.location`for the navigation from javascript